# Ошибка в сессии php

Tags: php, сессия

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код, который открывает сессию php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$admin_login="Admin"; //Логин админа
$admin_password="superpass"; //Пароль админа

if(isset($_POST['password'])):
$_SESSION[$_POST['login']]=$_POST['password'];
header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
exit;
endif;

if($_SESSION[$admin_login]!=$admin_password)
{
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/4/style.css">
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="login">
 <h1>Форма входа</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" autofocus required>   
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="ВОЙТИ">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<?php
exit;
}
else
{
   ?>

   <a href='/4/exit.php'>Выход</a>

<?php
}
?>
```

При создании и удалении сессии в error_log записывается такая ошибка

**PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Admin in /home/4/index.php on line 12**

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так он пишет что нет такого индекса, так и есть. Пока вы не зарегистрированы такой переменной и нет.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov как тогда избавиться от данного сообщения?

Comment: Дополнительная проверка есть ли она `if($_SESSION[$admin_login] && $_SESSION[$admin_login]!=$admin_password)` должно помочь

Comment: @RuslanSemenov не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду лучше всего

```
if($_SESSION[$admin_login]!=$admin_password)
```

исправить на

```
if(!isset($_SESSION[$admin_login]) || $_SESSION[$admin_login]!=$admin_password)
```

В таком случае сначала проверяется существование переменной. Если переменной нет или она не равна $admin_password, то срабатывает условие и выводится форма.

Comment: Большущие спасибо, все работает.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде есть переменная **$admin_login = "Admin"** и далее вы обращаетесь к ней как **$_SESSION[$admin_login]**, таким образом обращение выглядит вот так **$_SESSION['Admin']**, то есть значение этой переменной используется как индекс суперглобального масcива $_SESSION, скорее всего такого не существует в сессии. То есть у вас должно существовать что то вроде этого **$_SESSION['admin_login'] = $admin_login**, ранее опрделенное в сессии. Возможно я неправильно понял код, но на мой взгляд проблема в этом. Надеюсь Вам поможет.

Comment: Обозначил как вы сказали, увы не помогло.

Comment: Если эта переменная у вас определена в другом файле, то посмотрите что бы там обязательно была открыта сессия как в этом session_start();. Главное понимать, что в скобках [] указывается индекс ассоциативного суперглобального массива $_SESSION к которому привязано значение, если использовать в скобках в переменную без кавычек, в качестве индекса будет использоваться не сама переменная а ее значение.